# Python parser ply not matching token

Tags: python, ply

I am trying to use `Ply` to parse a file and am trying to make comment tokens. Comments are designated by either double slashes `//` or a hashtag `#`. When I try to use the following, no comment tokens are created.

```
@lex.TOKEN(r'(//.*|\#.*)')
def t_COMMENT(t):
    ...
```

I have also tried writing the token as follows with no results.

```
def t_COMMENT(t):
    r''(//.*|\#.*)'
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need the TOKEN decorator for that; you can just use a docstring. The TOKEN decorator is needed when the pattern to be matched is computed rather than being a known literal string, which is by far the most common (and is certainly the case here). But I don't think that answers your question. How do you know that "no comment tokens are created" (and why do you want to create comment tokens in the first place?). What is the *body* of your `t_COMMENT` function? (which is what is responsible for returning tokens).

Comment: I realize that the TOKEN decorator is probably unnessacery. It does not appear to make a difference whether I include it or not. I know that no comment tokens are created because I printed out the tokens that were generated and none were comments. The body of the function is exactly how I wrote it. It should not matter why I need to create comment tokens, but in case it helps, I am trying to parse a file (in an odd format) and generate a new file in a better format and want to preserve the comments.

Comment: Ah, I thought that ellipsis was standing in for some code which you didn't feel like typing, as opposed to being a replacement for the `pass` statement.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't matter why you want comment tokens, but it's a common mistake to generate tokens which just get in the way, so it's good to know that it was intentional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the Ply documentation says](https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn8) (with an example):

> #### 4.5 Discarded tokens
>
> To discard a token, such as a comment, simply define a token rule that returns no value. For example:
>
> ```
> def t_COMMENT(t):
>     r'\#.*'
>     pass
>     # No return value. Token discarded
> ```

Since that's what you are doing, the comment tokens are discarded. That's normally what is wanted, since comments just get in the way of parsing. But when you really want the comment tokens for some purpose, you'll need to either return `t` (or some other token) from your token function, or, even easier, use a [simple token variable](https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn6):

```py
t_COMMENT = r'(//|\#).*'
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you try this?

```
def t_COMMENT(t): r'\(//.*) | (#.*)'; return t
```